# Tidying up a powershell script

Tags: powershell

So I need help tidying up a script that I have. The purpose of this script is to make 18 different sql files based on the data below 18 different column headers. What my script does now is make 1 sql file based on which column I choose to input via "Read-Host". This is my current script

```
function get-header {
  Read-Host "Type the Column header betwen B-Z for which sql files needs to be created"
}

function get-column {
  Read-Host "Type the Column number"
}

do {
  $val = get-header
}
while (!$val)

do {
  $col = get-column
}
while (!$col)

switch ($val) {

  "B" {$column = "1"}
  "C" {$column = "2"}
  "D" {$column = "3"}
  "E" {$column = "4"}
  "F" {$column = "5"}
  "G" {$column = "6"}
  "H" {$column = "7"}
  "I" {$column = "8"}
  "J" {$column = "9"}
  "K" {$column = "10"}
  "L" {$column = "11"}
  "M" {$column = "12"}
  "N" {$column = "13"}
  "O" {$column = "14"}
  "P" {$column = "15"}
  "Q" {$column = "16"}
  "R" {$column = "17"}
  "S" {$column = "18"}
  "T" {$column = "19"}
  "U" {$column = "20"}
  "V" {$column = "21"}
  "W" {$column = "22"}
  "X" {$column = "23"}
  "Y" {$column = "24"}
  "Z" {$column = "25"}

  default {$column = 'Unknown'}
}

if ($column -eq 'Unknown') {
  Write-Warning "Not a valid input"
  return
}
       
$csv = Import-Csv "Indices Updates - September 2018.csv" -Header 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26

$date = (Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy").Replace("-","/")

$sql = @("INSERT INTO benchmark_values(created_at,benchmark_id,date,amount,created_by_username)

foreach ($data in $csv) {
  $secondcolumn = [int]$column + 1
  $sql += "('$date',$col,'$($data.1)',$($data.$secondcolumn),'BPylla'),"
}

$sql | Out-File "sqldata.sql"
```

Now I want to get rid of read-host entirely because I don't want to input any values. I also will give an example of what the csv file looks like and what the sql file should look like.

[image: CSV File Image]

[image: SQL File Image]

So the goal is to produce different sql files from each column of information using the the sql format posted. I already have the template for that in my script now, I just need the script to create all the sql files based on headers and still input the data below the headers in the new sql files. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are after. Just a hint instead of `-Header 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26` simply use `-Header @(1..26)`

Comment: Also most of your switch could be replaced by calculating `$Column=([int][char]$Val.ToUpper())-65`

Comment: Does that $column variable give you the column data?

Comment: @LotPings: Or, even simpler: `-Header (1..26)` - `@(...)` is never needed for expressions you know to be arrays (and is not only inefficient, but always outputs `[object[]]`, irrespective of the input array type - try `@([int[]] (1..3)).GetType().Name`).

Comment: @mklement0 so where and how would you apply that to the current script?

Comment: @AndrewFortes: My comment was just an aside on an LotPings' aside; it doesn't solve your problem, it merely allows you to simplify `-Header 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26` to `-Header (1..26)`

Comment: @AndrewFortes: I think your question is interesting in principle, but there's too much (incidental) code and the code could be formatted better, which is my guess as to why you haven't received answers yet. Generally, strive for an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).